# Read file to dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key

Let's say I have a CSV file below with data of some NFL players. My goal is to read the file, and create a dictionary with the keys as the positions, and the values as lists of player profiles in a tuple.

(NAME, AGE, HEIGHT, WEIGHT - Excluding the year they were drafted)

I'm confused on how to correctly create the dictionary while reading the file. What I have so far is at the bottom, but it's a mess.

```
POSITION,NAME,DRAFTED,AGE,HEIGHT,WEIGHT

QB,Aaron,2005,31,6,225

WR,Jordy,2008,30,6,217

WR,Randall,2011,24,5,192
```

Expected dictionary:

```
dict = {
        QB: [('Aaron', 31, 6, 225)]
        WR: [('Jordy', 30, 6, 217), ('Randall', 24, 5, 192)]
       }
       # Year drafted not included.
```

Mine:

```
def readTheFile(filename):

    read_it = open(filename, 'r')

    player_dict = {}

    #ignore header row
    readFile = read_it.readlines()[1:]

    for row in readFile:

        k,v = line.split()

        d[int(k)] = v

    return player_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)'s [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is what I'd use over the simple reader:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("players.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    players = list(reader)

# create position -> player mapping
player_by_position = defaultdict(list)
for player in players:
    player_by_position[player["POSITION"]].append(tuple(player.values()))

print player_by_position
```

It includes the player's position in the values, but I hope it's close enough :-) You can also leave the player as is to have a dictionary describing it by simply replacing:

```
player_by_position[player["POSITION"]].append(tuple(player.values()))
```

With:

```
player_by_position[player["POSITION"]].append(player)
```

---

Alternatively, your exact output can be achieved with iteration using the simple reader:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

player_by_position = defaultdict(list)

with open("players.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        player_by_position[row[0]].append(tuple(row[1:])

print player_by_position
```

---

**Edit** - Without imports:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

player_by_position = {}

with open("players.csv") as f:
    # skip headers
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        values = line.strip().split(",")
        if not values[0] in player_by_position:
            # new position - create new list of players for it
            player_by_position[values[0]] = []

        player_by_position[values[0]].append(tuple(values[1:]))

print player_by_position
```

Comment: Can the goal be achieved without importing anything?